# Correct Approach to GET JSON Data From Multiple REST Endpoints

Tags: java, json, rest, okhttp, endpoint

So, I am trying to determine the best way to go about getting/parsing JSON data from an existing web API.

What I mean is, given an endpoint like:

https://example.com/api/projects (not real)

which returns JSON structured like:

```
{
    "count": 4424,
    "results": [
        {"id": 2718, "name": "fox", "location": "Omaha"}, 
        {"id": 2719, "name": "bear", "location": "Miami"}
    ]
}
```

I need to then get a list of those id values in order to get the JSON from the subsequent endpoint which makes use of the project ID:

https://example.com/api/projects/**[id]**/resources (not real)

and returns JSON structured like:

```
{
    "quota_cpus": 2,
    "active_cpus": 1,
    "quota_memory": 16384,
    "active_memory": 0
}
```

What I was thinking was that I would use OKHTTP3 to make a REST call to retrieve the project IDs and store them in a java object called Project.

Then I was going to loop through the list and make another REST call to retrieve the list of resources for each individual project and store that in a new object called ProjectResources.

My questions are:

- Does that seem like the right approach to take?
- What better alternatives would you suggest?
- And should I make these synchronous or asynchronous calls?

Comment: sounds like you want a new endpoint from the server, are you in control of that component or can talk to its maintainers? Sure, your approach will work, and yes async if you can, but you will waste a lot of http calls

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have control of that component and can't get in touch with those who do. I guess given those constraints this is the approach to go with?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's answers to your queries,

Does that seem like the right approach to take?

> If you just need id's from first call response, then store them in a
> List instead of Project

.

What better alternatives would you suggest?

> Since second call depends on number of id's returned from first call,
> its better if you make async calls which will improve the execution
> time.
>
> But, if you have permission to change second endpoint, i would suggest
> to make it such that it accepts multiple ids.

And should I make these synchronous or asynchronous calls?

> You can make use of async call. (For example, using ExecutorServvice)